# can we use SNS for sending multiple email addresses as inputs in stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

How to give multiple email addresses as Inputs in `amazon SNS` as subscribers using stack. Just I want to take email address as input parameter and allowed it to take multiple email addresses as comma separated string i.e `CommaDelimitedList`, but it was not taken by `endpoint` in resource subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any methods in the API where multiple `SubscribeRequest` instances can be supplied as a collection. An instance of `SubcribeRequest` takes a single email.

Consequently I think you'd have to create your own wrapper method that takes a collection.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a bit late but i had similar situation with creating an Alarm in AWS CloudWatch. Form the UI once you select your topic (if you do not select one will be generated automatically) you could add multiple email subscribers as comma separated values (email@example.com, email_2@example.com etc.) who can receive the alert when the Alarm is triggered, but form code (C#) the way to do it for me was to add multiple subscriptions to the topic that i created pragmatically.